# Simple question about submersions

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism and $g: Y \rightarrow Z$ be a $C^1$-submersion in $y \in Y$.

1- I'm pretty sure that it is true, but $g \circ f$ is also a $C^1$-submersion in some point $x \in X$ right ?

2- Do we have in particular that $g \circ f$ is $C^1$-submersion in $f^{-1}(y)$ ? If yes, why ? If no, using $y$, can we find a particular point $x_y$ where $g \circ f$ is $C^1$-submersion in $x_y$ ?

EDIT: We have that $d_{f^{-1}(y)}(g \circ f) = d_yg \circ d_{f^{-1}(y)}f$, where $d_yg$ and $d_{f^{-1}(y)}f$ are surjective (by assumption). So we can conclude that $d_{f^{-1}(y)}(g \circ f)$ is also surjective ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $g$ is submersive at $y\in Y$, then $g\circ f$ is submersive at $f^{-1}(y)$. $df_{f^{-1}y}$ is an isomorphism from $T_{f^{-1}y}X$ to $T_yY$.

Comment: Thank you very much !